# Open several files placed in different folders

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

Hope someone can help me. My knowledge about R is quite basic and I get confused when I have to use loops and conditionals. The thing is that I have a folder (results). In this folder, I have several subfolders (01, 02, etc). Each of these subfolders has different files. One of these files is the file RESULTS_FILE (.cvs). This file has the same name in each subfolder and it is a data frame with different information. The first row of this data frame is the name of the variables. What I would like to do is to put all the RESULTS_FILE in one data frame. One important point is that in this new data frame only the first row should contain the names of the variables. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two steps:

1. Use `lapply` operating on the folder names to read in each data file using the `read.csv` function. This returns a list of data frames.
2. Use `do.call` with `rbind` to combine these data frames into a single data frame.

Assuming you've stored the names of all your folders in a vector `folders` with something like `folders <- c("foo", "bar")`, you could use:

```
dfs <- lapply(folders, function(f) read.csv(file.path(f, "RESULTS_FILE.cvs")))
dat <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
```

Comment: Note you should always construct paths with `file.path`, and then it will handle the slash separators for you. `file.path(f,"RESULTS_FILE.cvs")` is the way to go here.

Comment: @Spacedman updated to use `file.path` -- thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I didn´t think about using lapply and it makes sense. Thanks a lot!